# How to reduce delay in directing user to home Activity if he is connected?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

I am using Firebase for my Android Studio project.
In order to direct user from `MainActivity` which is the login activity to home `Activity`, I check if there is a current user, and in this case I make an intent to home `Activity`. The problem is, this takes a few seconds during which `MainActivity` is on screen, I know it takes time to connect to Firebase and check, but I don't notice this problem in other apps, so I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this time delay or there is some kind of trick.

this is the code I use :

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminHome.class));
      }
```

Comment: You can't speed up the network connection on a mobile device.  You will always pay the cost of moving bytes around.  I'd suggest not comparing your app to other apps, unless you know exactly what those other apps are doing.  They might not be requiring a user to be logged in (and maybe yours doesn't actually need to require it either).

Comment: You should consider using better names for your activities, e.g. `LoginActivity` `HomeActivity`  etc.

Comment: Consider sharing some code. For example: How do you check `if there is a current user`. It's impossible to suggest something useful when there's nothing to look at.

Comment: It is actually necessary that a user be logged in, and I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing this code in your AdminHome activity instead of your MainActivity. In AdminHome activity, check if the current user is null. If it is, redirect the user to the MainActivity.

Also as another user suggested, I would recommend renaming your MainActivity to SignInActivity and AdminHome to MainActivity